# CLLocationManager asks permission every time on Mountain Lion

Tags: permissions, cllocationmanager, osx-mountain-lion

My Mac Application asks Location permission just once on Snow Leopard and Lion OS versions.

But on Mountain Lion, it asks everytime user runs the application.

How to fix this ? Is there a way to request OS for a permanent permission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

Seems like Mountain Lion requires that an application's binary should be located in "Applications" folder to save permissions.

I dragged the app to Applications folder, and app asked for permission to access the user location one last time and never again.